# How to migrate oracle database from enterprise edition to standard edition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to migrating Oracle Database Enterprise Edition to a Standard Edition, I was wondering if anyone has experience doing this. I've searched around and I can't really find a definitive answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends if you are using any EE specific features.

See this link for a features list by edition as a start:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#DBLIC116

It's big things like RAC, Advanced Security that are EE only.

Assuming you are just looking to shift the data, you should be able to expdb out from EE then impdp into SE, provided you aren't using things like encryption.

In reality this is one of those exercises that will be very specific to your requirements and database. I would suggest you start off simple, with expdp, impdp, and see what issues fall out and deal with them.